# Weird JOIN interpretation from MySQL in Innodb

Tags: mysql

I have table called flight that has 2 relationships with a table called flight_aircraft.

Here is the structure of the tables

```
CREATE TABLE `flight` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  `scheduled_aircraft_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ...
  `actual_aircraft_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ...
  KEY `scheduled_aircraft_idx1` (`scheduled_aircraft_id`),
  KEY `actual_aircraft_idx1` (`actual_aircraft_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `flight_aircraft_actual_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`actual_aircraft_id`) REFERENCES `flight_aircraft` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `flight_aircraft_scheduled_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`scheduled_aircraft_id`) REFERENCES `flight_aircraft` (`id`),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56116 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `flight_aircraft` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `registration` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `seats_number` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `registration` (`registration`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=129 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The analyse mysql function returns me weird response on the joins.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM flight flight        
    -> JOIN flight_aircraft actual_flight_aircraft   
    ->   ON actual_flight_aircraft.id = flight.actual_aircraft_id;
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref                               | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | actual_flight_aircraft | ALL  | PRIMARY              | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                              |   67 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | flight                 | ref  | actual_aircraft_idx1 | actual_aircraft_idx1 | 4       | mercure.actual_flight_aircraft.id |  439 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM flight flight  JOIN flight_aircraft scheduled_flight_aircraft            
    ->     ON scheduled_flight_aircraft.id = flight.scheduled_aircraft_id;
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | scheduled_flight_aircraft | ALL  | PRIMARY                 | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL                                 |   67 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | flight                    | ref  | scheduled_aircraft_idx1 | scheduled_aircraft_idx1 | 4       | mercure.scheduled_flight_aircraft.id |  439 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM flight flight        
    -> JOIN flight_aircraft actual_flight_aircraft   
    ->   ON actual_flight_aircraft.id = flight.actual_aircraft_id
    -> JOIN flight_aircraft scheduled_flight_aircraft            
    ->     ON scheduled_flight_aircraft.id = flight.scheduled_aircraft_id;
+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type   | possible_keys                                | key                  | key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | actual_flight_aircraft    | ALL    | PRIMARY                                      | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                                 |   67 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | flight                    | ref    | scheduled_aircraft_idx1,actual_aircraft_idx1 | actual_aircraft_idx1 | 4       | mercure.actual_flight_aircraft.id    |  439 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | scheduled_flight_aircraft | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY              | 4       | mercure.flight.scheduled_aircraft_id |    1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0,01 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM flight flight 
    -> JOIN flight_aircraft scheduled_flight_aircraft            
    ->     ON scheduled_flight_aircraft.id = flight.scheduled_aircraft_id       
    -> JOIN flight_aircraft actual_flight_aircraft   
    ->   ON actual_flight_aircraft.id = flight.actual_aircraft_id
    -> 
    -> WHERE 1
    -> LIMIT 20;;
+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type   | possible_keys                                | key                     | key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | scheduled_flight_aircraft | ALL    | PRIMARY                                      | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL                                 |   67 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | flight                    | ref    | scheduled_aircraft_idx1,actual_aircraft_idx1 | scheduled_aircraft_idx1 | 4       | mercure.scheduled_flight_aircraft.id |  439 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | actual_flight_aircraft    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY                 | 4       | mercure.flight.actual_aircraft_id    |    1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I do not understand why mysql cannot find the related constraint and/or the index to be able to interprete the query correctly.

Did anyone experienced this problem ?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
What I would have expect from mysql is the flight table to be always the first in the EXPLAIN result. And it was before the flight table got quite big (56k) compare to the flight_aircraft table (129 rows).
MySQL changes its behaviour around 50k rows parsing the flight_aircraft first.

Comment: Why do you believe something is wrong with the query "interpretation"?

Comment: I'm not an expert in reading MySQL explain plans. Could you clarify what is wrong about them?

Also for the insert problem: It would help if you show what you are actually trying toot insert.

Comment: I am strongly thinking that when execute a query : 
1. the "from" table should always be the first on the analyse response.
2. mysql should use the key PRIMARY to do the join on the relationship

Comment: STRAIGHT_JOIN instead of JOIN seems to help...

Comment: "the "from" table should always be the first" - That would be true for (real) LEFT JOINs or (as you figured out) for STRIGHT_JOINs. Usually you shouldn't care about the execution plan. I guess you don't like the data you get because of how they are sorted. But then you should fix it with a proper ORDER BY clause instead of STRIGHT_JOIN. When I see LIMIT without ORDER BY I'm pretty sure - something is wrong.

Comment: The problem was not the data I was getting but how slow the query was executed. The queries I putted are an example not the actual queries. I think a similar problem was here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50727/mysql-not-using-indexes-when-joining-against-another-table...